Covering Vacuum Hepa Filter with Tissue Paper
I recently purchased a hand-held vacuum that comes with a non washable HEPA filter which is covered with a layer of thin sponge.
Since the HEPA filter is non washable, cleaning it is really cumbersome. I have to tap it several times on my sink to take out all the dust from it.
However, I recently watched a video where this guy covered the Hepa filter of his portable vacuum with a tissue paper and after vacuuming, it can be seen that all the dust has collected all around the tissue paper. He then just unwraps and discards the paper. The filter doesn't need to be cleaned that way, that's what he claims.
Is this possible? Does it cause any trouble to the VC itself?

It will tax the motor more (even if just slightly) and it would reduce suction and could lessen the life of the vacuum.  I think this would go for anything with a motor/blower like this.

It may restrict airflow, compromise filter efficiency, and cause heat buildup.


Is this possible?

If you saw it being done, then yes, it is possible.

Does it cause any trouble to the VC itself?

Possibly. It depends on several factors, the most important being how much harder the motor needs to work.


hand-held vacuum that comes with a non washable HEPA filter

You did not provide details about the vacuum, so I cannot be sure if this applies to you. But the idea is that "non-washable" means that you throw it away when it is full and buy another one. Just like the non-washable bags for standard vacuum cleaners.
Usually the HEPA filter is supposed to be the finest filter in the vacuum, for the smallest particles. If you can add something that can collect more than the HEPA filter, then you need to re-evaluate the filtering capabilities of the HEPA filter. Also, you need to consider that if the extra filter (the paper tissue) is too tight, the motor will work too hard with the risk of giving away its ghost - or at least, considerably shortening its life.


Since the HEPA filter is non washable, cleaning it is really cumbersome.

HEPA filters filter down to 0.3 micro-meters. You are unlikely to be able to clean that anyway.

So, the next time when you shop for vacuums, decide first what kind of filtration you want / need. What size of the particles, wet or dry, cyclone, HEPA etc., washable or not, cleanable or not etc. Research the prices of filters. Consider that as the vacuum gets older, the availability of filters will become an issue too.
So... it is possible that you made a bad shopping decision (you bought non-washable when in fact you wanted washable). Only your experience can tell you the truth.
